# Old Portrayal of St Michael the Archangel

Tags: angels, resource-request, art, michael

I am searching for a painting of the Archangel Michael, but with the old portrayal.
In every painting I have found he is depicted with a sword, literally fighting the bad and everything dark.
 As far as I know there is at least one painting where he doesn't have a sword to fight the other side, but he reaches literally into the dark. In this portrait he does this to give everything dark a chance, he isn't denying the path to the light for everything bad.

I already found the below painting, but it doesn't exactly depict what I am thinking about.

[image: Painting]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for art.

Comment: Are you looking for a particular style of art?  Renaissance, I'm guessing?   @curious is right that this is off-topic if you're just looking for people to help you find a picture, but I think it's highly topical if you're looking for a particular piece that was painted that way for a particular reason.

Comment: While I like the question, I also am voting to close because it is not about "Christianity", but about art.

Comment: @PeterTurner I am not looking for a particular piece, but any picture that expressed St. Michael that way. I am happy i find only one.

Comment: @florian OK, then I have to agree with curiousdannii I would change the question to "Is St. Michael ever portrayed...."  that would be more topical and might actually garner answers.